# How to fix "invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'" error?

Tags: c++

I have a problem in compiling this source . 
This is my source :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char pass[7],d;
int v;

int isvalid(char pass);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout<<"Enter Password :";
    gets(pass);
    cout<<endl;
    v=isvalid (pass);
    if(v==1){
        cout<<"The Password is Correct . You can Come in"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The Password in InCorrect ! You Can't Come In"<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
/*-----------Functions--------------*/
int isvalid(char pass){
    d="Pokerface";
    if(pass==d){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It should get a password from user and check it with isvalid function and say  It is correct or not but compiler (DEV C++ 5) shows me these errors :

```
    In function 'int main(int, char**)':
14  17      [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
8   5       [Note] initializing argument 1 of 'int isvalid(char)'
    In function 'int isvalid(char)':
26  3   [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
28      recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

What is the problem ? please help me.

Comment: variable `pass` is of type `char*` not `char`. there is difference between them. `char*` is pointer to char. change argument type of function `isvalid` as `char*` instead of `char` and then modify method.

Comment: char is 1 byte, char* is a 4 byte pointer pointing to the first char in an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pass` is an array of char ( `char *` ), and your `isvalid` funciton take a `char`as it's first argument. I suspect you want to change your `isvalid` function so that it takes a `char*` as an argument, like this :

`int isvalid(char* pass){`

Also, keep in mind that when you do this :

`if (pass==d)`

You are NOT comparing the strings, but the pointers. If you want to check that the two string are identical, that's not going to work

For strings comparisons use `strcmp(str1, str2)` in `string.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged C++ to this question, I would suggest using `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isvalid(const std::string & pass);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    string pass;
    cout << "Enter Password" << endl;
    cin >> pass;
    if (isvalid(pass))
        cout << "The Password is Correct. You can Come in" << endl;
    else
        cout << "The Password in InCorrect ! You Can't Come In" << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isvalid(const std::string & pass) {
    return pass == "Pokerface";
}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb sure, fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
int isvalid(char pass)
```

You probably meant to take in a `char*` there, but you shouldn't do that either: use `std::string` instead. Additionally, your function should return a `bool` instead of an `int`.

```
bool isvalid(const std::string& pass)
```

You should then update  `pass` and `d` to be `std::string`s as well and use `std::cin` instead of `gets` to read from `stdin`. There is no reason for `pass` or `d` to be global variables, so make them local to your functions.

If you keep your function as taking a `char*` your comparison will not work, because you will just be comparing the pointers. You would need `strncmp` for that.